# SocketMobile ScanAPI connects and works on Android phone but does not connect on Android Tablet

Tags: android, bluetooth, socketmobile

i have successfully integrated the ScanAPI SDK into my android application which runs on both android smartphones and tablets,i tested it on some few android smartphones,it connected and scan with no problem ,but when i run my application on an android tablet it does not connect ,and returns an error

> ScanApi Failed to initialise with error -34

Answer (score 0):

My app did not have the right permissions to start ScanAPI , even though i had the permissions requested in the manifest , i had to request the permission at runtime and it worked successfully .